# Can't publish API doc to GitHub Pages

Tags: github-pages, github-actions, api-doc

Here's my `.github/workflows/publish-apidocs.yml`:

```
name: Publish API docs

on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout ️
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.1
        with:
          persist-credentials: false
      - name: Install and Build 
        run: | # Install npm packages and build the Apidocs files
          npm install
          npm run docs
          test -e ~/docs-build/index.html && echo file exists || echo file not found
      - name: Deploy 
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@3.6.2
        with:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          BRANCH: prod # The branch the action should deploy to.
          FOLDER: docs-build # The folder that the docs script generates files.
          CLEAN: true # Automatically remove deleted files from the deploy branch
          TARGET_FOLDER: docs # The folder that we serve our Apidocs files from
```

My package.json script:

```
"docs": "apidoc -i src -o docs-build",
```

And the GitHub Pages settings:
[image: Github Pages settings]

I also tried creating `apidoc.json` file and it doesn't help either:

```
{
  "name": " Mavka Api documentation",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Documentation for the REST api access provided at Mavka.org",
  "sampleUrl": "https://mavka-api-5dvjwdatfq-ey.a.run.app"
}
```

This yields:

```
Run npm install

> nodemon@2.0.7 postinstall /home/runner/work/mavka-api/mavka-api/node_modules/nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0


> mongodb-memory-server@6.9.6 postinstall /home/runner/work/mavka-api/mavka-api/node_modules/mongodb-memory-server
> node ./postinstall.js

mongodb-memory-server: checking MongoDB binaries cache...
Downloading MongoDB 4.0.14: 0 % (0mb / 99.4mb)
mongodb-memory-server: binary path is /home/runner/work/mavka-api/mavka-api/node_modules/.cache/mongodb-memory-server/mongodb-binaries/4.0.14/mongod

> sinon@4.5.0 postinstall /home/runner/work/mavka-api/mavka-api/node_modules/sinon
> node scripts/support-sinon.js

Have some ❤️ for Sinon? You can support the project via Open Collective:
 > https://opencollective.com/sinon/donate

npm WARN mavka-api@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN mavka-api@0.0.0 No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

added 1228 packages from 848 contributors and audited 1231 packages in 24.298s

81 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 2 vulnerabilities (1 low, 1 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

> mavka-api@0.0.0 docs /home/runner/work/mavka-api/mavka-api
> apidoc -i src -o docs-build

{"message":"Please create an apidoc.json configuration file.","level":"warn"}

> mavka-api@0.0.0 postdocs /home/runner/work/mavka-api/mavka-api
> open-cli docs-build/index.html

file not found
```

So, it seems like doesn't actually build the `docs-build` folder when done through Github Actions (because there is no `/docs-build/index.html` file. It does build it when I run it through my Windows command line. Do you know what the issue could be? Here's the repo with full code: https://github.com/mavka-org/mavka-api